# PyQt Webkit and html forms: Fetching output and closing window

Tags: python, webkit, pyqt4, forms

I am trying to get a borderless python PyQt webkit window to display a single website html form. When clicking on send, the form values should be saved in a dictionnary and the window closed.

So far (with the help of a [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10237534/289572)) I have the borderless window and can fetch the input. However, two things are missing:

1. Closing the window after pressing send.
2. Fetching the input in the dictionary `elements` (note that the keys of `elements` correspond to the html form names).

(potentially the other way round would be better, but 1 seems more difficult)

My code so far is:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

elements = {"like":"", "text": ""}

class MyWebPage(QWebPage):
    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, frame, req, nav_type):
        if nav_type == QWebPage.NavigationTypeFormSubmitted:
            text = "<br/>\n".join(["%s: %s" % pair for pair in req.url().queryItems()])
            print(text)
            return True
        else:
            return super(MyWebPage, self).acceptNavigationRequest(frame, req, nav_type)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, html):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        view = QWebView(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(view)
        view.setPage(MyWebPage())
        view.setHtml(html)


# setup the html form
html = """
<form action="" method="get">
Like it?
<input type="radio" name="like" value="yes"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="like" value="no" /> No
<br/><input type="text" name="text" value="Hello" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
"""

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Window(html)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A perfect answer would not only show how to **(a) save the input** and **(b) close the window**, but **(c) also remove the remaining small grey border around the html page**.

**Update**: I use Python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the form data into a `dict`, it is best to use [`unquote_plus`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus) from the python standard library as (unlike `QUrl`) it can handle plus-signs as well as percent-encoding.

To close the window, you could emit a `formSubmitted` signal from the web-page, and connect it to a handler on the main-window. This handler could then call `close()` on the main-window, do all the processing of the form data, and then finally `quit()` the application.

To remove the border around the page, set the [`contentsMargins`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qlayout.html#contentsMargins) of the main layout to zero.

Here is revised version of your script which implements the above ideas:

```
import sys
from urllib import unquote_plus

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class MyWebPage(QWebPage):
    formSubmitted = pyqtSignal(QUrl)

    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, frame, req, nav_type):
        if nav_type == QWebPage.NavigationTypeFormSubmitted:
            self.formSubmitted.emit(req.url())
        return super(MyWebPage, self).acceptNavigationRequest(frame, req, nav_type)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, html):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        view = QWebView(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(view)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        view.setPage(MyWebPage())
        view.setHtml(html)
        view.page().formSubmitted.connect(self.handleFormSubmitted)

    def handleFormSubmitted(self, url):
        self.close()
        elements = {}
        for key, value in url.encodedQueryItems():
            key = unquote_plus(bytes(key)).decode('utf8')
            value = unquote_plus(bytes(value)).decode('utf8')
            elements[key] = value
        # do stuff with elements...
        for item in elements.iteritems():
            print '"%s" = "%s"' % item
        qApp.quit()

# setup the html form
html = """
<form action="" method="get">
Like it?
<input type="radio" name="like" value="yes"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="like" value="no" /> No
<br/><input type="text" name="text" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
"""

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Window(html)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks awesome. Unfortunately I use python 2.

Comment: @Henrik. Sorry about that. Now converted to work with python2.

Comment: This is so great. Thanks a lot. If I could, I would hug you immediately!

Comment: I tried to implement it in a way that you can display two website in succession (each time calling `app.exec_()`) but didn't manage to do so, can perhaps extend the answer?